# How to display internal User ID instead of Client ID (ga cookie), in Google Analytics via GTM?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

I have surfaced my system's user id to display as a JS variable. I created a Custom Dimension to pull that user id, and connect it to the client id provided by Google.

Here's the dimension's code...

```
function() {
  try {
    var tracker = ga.getAll()[0];
    return tracker.get('clientId');
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("Error fetching ID");
    return "Customer ID N/A";
  }
}
```

The variable that displays our User ID is **ECID**. I've tried every which way I can think of, but the only thing that works is what's above. I don't want the cookie id. I want to be able to display our internal User ID.

Here's how the event fires...

[image]

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, but the goal is to have something like this (pulled from a YT video)...

[image]

Comment: the code that you have pasted is to get the client id. I dont see any place where you have picked up your user id. Is that user id in dataLayer? If yes then pick it up as a dataLayer variable suing GTM.

Comment: @Tushar - this is my confusion. Can you explain your response in a little more detail?

Comment: Is ECID (your data you want to use as user id) already available in dataLayer, or is it stored in a cookie or a JavaSript variable?

Comment: It's stored as a js variable.

Answer (score 1):

While creating the view you need to enable User_Id reports . Then only it will show user_id instead of client_id